# create two functions in python

Tags: python, algorithm

i have these task which i believe i have done well to some level

Create a function get_algorithm_result to implement the algorithm below

1- Get a list of numbers L1, L2, L3....LN as argument
   2- Assume L1 is the largest, Largest = L1
   3- Take next number Li from the list and do the following
   4- If Largest is less than Li
   5- Largest = Li
   6- If Li is last number from the list then
   7- return Largest and come out
   8- Else repeat same process starting from step 3

Create a function prime_number that does the following
Takes as parameter an integer and
Returns boolean value true if the value is prime or
Returns boolean value false if the value is not prime

so i came up with this code below

```
def get_algorithm_result(my_list):
if not any(not type(y) is int for y in my_list):
    largest = 0
    for item in range(0,len(my_list)):
        if largest < my_list[item]:
            largest = my_list[item]
    return largest
else:

    return(my_list[-1])

def prime_number(integer):
if integer%2==0 and 2!=integer:
    return False
else:
    return True

get_algorithm_result([1, 78, 34, 12, 10, 3])     
get_algorithm_result(["apples", "oranges", "mangoes", "banana", "zoo"]) 
prime_number(1) 
prime_number(78) 
prime_number(11)
```

for the question above, there is a unittes which reads

```
import unittest

class AlgorithmTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_maximum_number_one(self):
    result = get_algorithm_result([1, 78, 34, 12, 10, 3])
    self.assertEqual(result, 78, msg="Incorrect number")

  def test_maximum_number_two(self):
    result = get_algorithm_result(["apples", "oranges", "mangoes", "banana", "zoo"])
self.assertEqual(result, "zoo", msg="Incorrect number")

  def test_prime_number_one(self):
    result = prime_number(1)
    self.assertEqual(result, True, msg="Result is invalid")

  def test_prime_number_two(self):
    result = prime_number(78)
    self.assertEqual(result, False, msg="Result is invalid")

  def test_prime_number_three(self):
    result = prime_number(11)
    self.assertEqual(result, True, msg="Result is invalid")
```

but once i run my code ,it returns error saying 
    Test Spec Failed

```
Your solution failed to pass all the tests
```

what is actually wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yourself by including print statements? Narrow the problem down as much as possible before asking a question, that will raise the chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Are you sure you know what a prime number is? You're testing whether the input is odd or 2.

Comment: Every number not divisible by two is prime?

Comment: your prime checking algorithm is just plain wrong, you should implement the [trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Trial_division) algorithm as the more easy of all prime checking algorithm. Yours other one is almost ok, but you fail to follow the very clear instructions in it, you should do `largest = my_list[0]` to start and then iterate from 1, the type checking is unnecessary, let it trow a exception if a list of something that is not comparable is given to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution..**

```
 def get_algorithm_result(num_list):    
    largest =num_list[0]        
    for item in range(0,len(num_list)):    
        if largest < num_list[item]:                
            largest = num_list[item]    
    return largest

def prime_number(integer):
 if integer == 1:
   return False
 elif integer == 3:
   return True
 if integer > 3:
   for i in range(3, (integer-1)):
     if integer % i == 0:
       return False
  else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help for the prime

```
def prime_number(integer): 
  if integer == 1: return True
  if integer == 2: return True
  if integer == 3: return True
  if integer % 2 == 0: return False
  if integer % 3 == 0: return False
  else: return True
```